# Evaluate $\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^5}{z^6-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^5}{z^6-1}$$ where $\gamma=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\,|\,x^2+4y^2=16\}$.

How should I approach this? first to find the singularities by $z^6-1=0\iff z^6=1$

And then to plug each singularity in  $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}x^2+4y^2=16\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle): define $f(z)=z^6-1$. Then your integral is $\frac16\int_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,\mathrm dz$. By the argument principle, this is equal to $\frac16\times2\pi i$ times the number of zeros minus the number of poles of $f$ in the region of $\mathbb C$ enclosed by $\gamma$. Since there are six zeros and no poles there, the answer is $2\pi i$.

Comment: Why there is no poles?

Comment: @gbox Polynomial functions don't have poles.

Comment: What about those https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_(complex_analysis)#Examples?

Comment: @gbox *You* tell me: what about them? None of them is about polynomial functions, except the last one, which has a pole at $\infty$, which is something that we don't have to deal with in the context of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the curve $\gamma$ (ellipse centered at the origin with semiaxis $2$ and $4$) contains all the finite poles of the rational function $\frac{z^5}{z^6-1}$ ($6$ poles on the unit circle centered at the origin), it follows that
\begin{align*}\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^5}{z^6-1}dz&=-2\pi i\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{z^5}{z^6-1},\infty\right)=2\pi i\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1/z^5}{z^2(1/z^6-1)},0\right)\\
&=2\pi i\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(1-z^6)},0\right)=
2\pi i\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1+z^6+o(z^6)}{z},0\right)=2\pi i
\end{align*}
where we used the notion of [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity).

Comment: But they are not poles

Comment: @gboxYes, the rational function $\frac{z^5}{z^6-1}$ HAS 6 poles. In the other answer $f$ is $z^6-1$ which is a polynomial and therefore it has no poles.

Comment: @gbox Any further doubt? Note that my approach works easily also if you replace $z^5$ at the numerator with another power of $z$.